# HashMap object value not being read by c:if

Tags: java, jsp

I'm mapping some object instances to a Form.
For that I intend to use a c:foreach loop in a JSP page.

Im using spring MVC and Models are being passed to JSP correctly, except the attribute where there is a HashMap which will be read by the c:foreach loop.

Look:

Jsp (analysis/analysisConfig):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="analysisForm" action="analize" method="post"
        id="analysisForm">

        <label for="sampling"><spring:message code='analysis.sampling' /></label>
        <input type="text" id="sampling" name="sampling" />
        <br />
        <c:forEach items="${analysisTypes}" var="type">
            <label for="${type.key.name}"><spring:message
                    code='${type.key.message}' /></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="${type.key.name}" name="${type.key.name}"
                value="${type.value}" />
        </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Code from the Analysis Controller class:

```
private static Map<IAnalysisType, Boolean> analysisTypes = new HashMap<IAnalysisType, Boolean>();

    //Configure here all analysis Types to be shown
    static{
        analysisTypes.put(new AnalysisRMS(), false);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="configuration", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String config(@ModelAttribute("analysisForm") AnalysisForm form, @ModelAttribute("fileName") String fileName, Model model){
        if(fileName!= null && fileName!=""){
            form.setAnalysisTypes(AnalysisController.analysisTypes);
            form.setFileName(fileName);
            model.addAttribute("analysisForm", form);
            return "analysis/analysisConfig";
        } else {
            return "index";
        }
```

Interface which is being used for polymorphism:

```
public interface IAnalysisType {

    public String getName();
    public String getMessage();
    public AnalysisResult execute(String samples);

}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

When you use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a Map, each item in the iteration is an instance of **Map.Entry**. That is each item in `var="type"` will return an instance of [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

So given your example:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${analysisTypes}">
   Key is ${type.key}
   Value is ${type.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that and I'm using this in the code. Is the way I wrote the code wrong? Like in ${type.key.name}, should I make a variable from key and get name from it?

Comment: I suggest to get an idea of what is Map.Entry class is.

Comment: So I cannot create anything from a hashMap because after iteration items are lost?

Comment: What is Map.Entry?

Comment: It is a key value pair, which maps one object/type to some other.